(Android Studio) Как правильно исползовать Rules в Network Inspector?
Я использую Android Studio Jellyfish, чтобы тестировать запросы. Для этого я использую Rules в Network Inspector, чтобы заменить код с 200 на 401 для конкретного запроса. Проблема в том, что в Network Inspector я вижу, что код был заменен:

Но запутывает, то что я так же поставил лог в коде
...
        val response: Response<ActiveSubscription> = repo.getActiveSubscriptionState()

        Log.e("HERE", ">>> getActiveSubscriptionState: $response")
...

и получаю вот такое
>>> getActiveSubscriptionState: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=...}

Получается, что в Network Inspector я вижу, что код был изменен, но в коде я все еще получаю правильно значение. Что не так?

Может снова баг вернулся? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77586240/5479247

@EugeneKrivenja да, может так как описание похоже на то, что происходит и у меня. Есть еще версия, что само приложение может кешировать результат в то время как Network Profiler показывает, что код поменялся... Не совсем понятно, как это можно проверть
